# How do I iterate over a dictionary for a specific key, then ading it to a new dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, append

I know this is a noob question but I'm a new learner to Python and I'm struggling with dictionaries.

I think my code is right but I'm not sure.

What I am trying to achieve is that I want to iterate over a dictionary with a list items with a dictionary in it. If the value is == None then that key Should be skipped. but if there is a value. I want to append the Key:Value pair to the pmp_dict = {}

Here is my code:

```
 input_dict = {
    "operation": {
        "Details": {
            "ACCOUNTLIST": {
                "RESOURCENAME": "abbas",
                "ACCOUNTNAME": "account_name",
                "RESOURCETYPE":None,
                "PASSWORD": "password"
            }
        }
    }
}

pmp_dict= {
    "operation": {
        "Details": {
            "ACCOUNTLIST": [
                {
                
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}

print(pmp_dict)

for list_item in input_dict["operation"]["Details"]["ACCOUNTLIST"]:
    for key, value in list_item.items():
        if value == None:
            pass
        else:
            pmp_dict["operation"]["Details"]["ACCOUNTLIST"][key]=value
```

what Im struggling with is the last 5 lines. how do i write so that i achieve the desired outcome? i know what i want to do but not the syntax for it.

Comment: If you do a print on `key` and `value` are the values you're expecting printing? Also your append method isn't appending anything. You need to pass something to the append method.

Comment: what are you trying to do? Provide expected output with multiple dicts please

Comment: @MalcolmInTheCenter ive shortened my code so it more apperent, any help is welcome

Comment: `pmp_dict["operation"]["Details"]["ACCOUNTLIST"][key]=value` should be `pmp_dict["operation"]["Details"]["ACCOUNTLIST"][key].append(value)`

Comment: @MalcolmInTheCenter hmmm that dossent seem to work :S

'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 30, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
> 

'

Comment: do `print(key, value)` right above `if value == None:`
what does it show?

Comment: @MalcolmInTheCenter it dose nothing

Comment: what does `print(list_item.items())` print ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's 2 problems with the code you have:

1.`pmp_dict["operation"]["Details"]["ACCOUNTLIST"]`
isn't a dictionary, it's a list. Unless this was intentional, I would replace

```
pmp_dict= {
    "operation": {
        "Details": {
            "ACCOUNTLIST": [
                {
            
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

with

```
pmp_dict = {
    "operation": {
        "Details": {
            "ACCOUNTLIST": {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

2. You don't need to iterate through the dictionary using

`for list_item in input_dict["operation"]["Details"]["ACCOUNTLIST"]:`

So instead, replace the last 6 lines of your code with

```
for key, value in input_dict["operation"]["Details"]["ACCOUNTLIST"].items():
    if value == None:
        pass
    else:
        pmp_dict["operation"]["Details"]["ACCOUNTLIST"][key] = value
```